# How to control which mp3 files to play using Java script on Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, audio, qualtrics

I am very new to coding a Java script and am trying to embed script lines that enable Qualtrics to play two types (i.e., [High](http://www.chrisasplund.com/AAB-SiD/High.mp3) or [Low](http://www.chrisasplund.com/AAB-SiD/Low.mp3)) of sounds (mp3 files uploaded on the website) depending on the response of a participant.

Below Java script embedded in Qualtrics' survey enables me to detect the keyboard press for the answer instead of mouse click (i.e., clicking a bubble among multiple choice radio button which can be quite time consuming).

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/
    this.hideNextButton();
    this.hidePreviousButton();

    var that = this;

    Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
      var choiceID = null;

      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 72: // 'h' was pressed
          choiceID = 1;
          break;
        case 76: // 'l' was pressed
          choiceID = 2;
          break;
      }

      if (choiceID) {
        Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
        that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
        that.clickNextButton();
      }
    });
});
```

I would very much appreciate it if someone could teach me possible lines that could be inserted below the clines of "choiceID = 1" or "choiceID = 2" to play the selected mp3 files (i.e., if choiceID==1 then play High.mp3; if choiceID==2 then play Low.mp3).

I use the below Qualtrics' source code to autoplay the mp3 files in the survey. So I think I need some Java script lines to execute the Qualtrics' source line like below.

```
&nbsp;
<audio autoplay="" src="http://www.chrisasplund.com/AAB-SiD/High.mp3">&nbsp;</audio>
```

Thank you so much for your time and kindness!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to your audio tags like:

```
<audio id="high" autoplay="" src="http://www.chrisasplund.com/AAB-SiD/High.mp3">&nbsp;</audio>
```

Then, to play it:

```
$('high').play();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a concise and amazingly helpful answer! This works perfectly!!! :)